# Update various strings.xml for valid reason

Tags: android, runtime, multilingual

I'm developing an application which is multi-lingual supported. Now i have not filled my values folder with any strings. My doubt is

- I want to fetch the string file contents for various languages only at runtime from my server. (bcoz i don't want to give an update if i changed a single string of any language). Is it possible.

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: `only at runtime from my server` - So, if your users aren't connected, they won't see any text?

Comment: it's possible if you provide your own implementation for the localization.

Comment: @DerGolem He could have a cached one in his initial apk and download new ones as needed when connected.  Still not worth it IMO, but it isn't unsolvable.

Comment: @GabeSechan Well, then I'd use a database where to download the localized resources (a table per each language), once connected. And use that one as a "cache" when disconnected.

Comment: @GabeSechan : So, providing my own implementation by using a DB and hadling it on changing the language is the final way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly-  the android string system requires everything to be in resources at compile time.  Of course, you can always just not use that and provide your own string lookup.  Back in the mid-2000s we did that on some big websites with a Berkley DB of all the various strings in each language, and we just pulled new DBs as needed.  But to do something like that you'd have to completely not use Android's built in system and roll your own.

Comment: So, providing my own implementation by using a DB and hadling it on changing the language is the final way?
At first time i refer a string as R.string.app_name. How could i change it after i filled my DB. (i mean the reference).